# Combine tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables containing some bank info like below.

```
Create table dbo.MainBank
(
     tmp1ID int,
     ID int not null,
     temptableID int not null,
     CountryID int
)

insert into dbo.MainBank values(1, 22, 9999, 56)

Create table dbo.BankBranches
(
     tmp1ID int,
     CountryID int, 
     BankBranchName varchar(200), 
     BranchID int,
     temptableID int not null
)

insert into dbo.BankBranches values(0, 56, 'Near Giant Store', 1000, 9999)
insert into dbo.BankBranches values(0, 56, 'Inside DM Mall', 2000, 9999)
insert into dbo.BankBranches values(0, 56, 'Near Hwy 20', 3000, 9999)
insert into dbo.BankBranches values(0, 56, '24 Salem St', 4000, 9999)
```

I want to iterate through all values of `dbo.BankBranches` for every match of ID from `dbo.MainBank`.

```
create table dbo.result
(
     tmp1ID int, 
     CountryID int,
     temptableID int, 
     BankBranchName varchar(200), 
     BranchID int
)

INSERT INTO dbo.result values(1, 56, 9999, 'Near Giant Store', 1000)
INSERT INTO dbo.result values(1, 56, 9999, 'Inside DM Mall', 2000)
INSERT INTO dbo.result values(1, 56, 9999, 'Near Hwy 20', 3000)
INSERT INTO dbo.result values(1, 56, 9999, '24 Salem St', 4000)
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean all values from BankBranches and those values from MainBank where BankBranches.BranchID = MainBank.temptableID:

```
select BB.*
      ,MB.*
From BankBranches BB
Left Join MainBank MB
on BB.BranchID = MB.temptableID
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example data and the your desired results, I am guessing the `ID` you are looking to join on is `temptableID`.

You can use an inner join, since we only want to return records in common between the two tables:

```
select  mb.tmp1ID,
        mb.CountryID,
        mb.temptableID,
        bb.BankBranchName,
        bb.BranchID
from dbo.MainBank mb
inner join dbo.BankBranches bb
    on mb.temptableID = bb.temptableID
```